# White Screen on open qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1

Tags: java, flutter, qr-code, flutter-method-channel

I'm openning the scanner of qr_code_scanner plugin and getting a white screen and this error:

E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:521)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.View.(View.java:5216)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.View.(View.java:5358)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:709)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:705)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:701)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:697)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview.(CameraPreview.java:228)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView.(BarcodeView.java:76)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr.CustomFramingRectBarcodeView.(CustomFramingRectBarcodeView.kt:12)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr.QRView.initBarCodeView(QRView.kt:197)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr.QRView.getView(QRView.kt:191)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:188)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:874)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:521)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:257)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:214)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:107)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(27605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)

flutter doctor:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky6x7.png)

Comment: Check one time both android & iOS platform integration required steps added correctly, and then flutter clean, flutter pub get & uninstall app & re-install it again.

Comment: The integration is added correctly, the problem occurs when I start a flutter activity as the flutter documentation says, here -> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen

Once I do that, the white screen appears, but if I dont do that, everything work correctly